# Readline into Tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, tuples

I would like to read a file line by line and break down each word group into an n-length tuple or list. For example:

```
@16 @ties-2  -> '@','16',' ','@','ties-2'  
5=3+2 -> '5','=','3','+','2'
```

Are there any existing ways of handling such data or am I going to be writing my own parser from scratch?

Comment: Lookup regular expressions

Comment: First, define what you mean by "word group" a little more closely.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this is asking for a recommendation of a **tool or software library**.

Comment: You need a parser. Try [PyParsing](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following could be used in Python:

```
import re

lines = ["@16 @ties-2", "5=3+2"]

for line in lines:
    print [x for x in re.split("(?<=@)([-a-z0-9]+)|([0-9=+-])|( )", line) if x]
```

This would display the following:

```
['@', '16', ' ', '@', 'ties-2']
['5', '=', '3', '+', '2']
```

If tuples are really needed rather than just a list, wrap the return from the list comprehension in a `tuple()` call. Tested using Python 2.7.

To read from a file:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        print tuple([x for x in re.split("(?<=@)([-a-z0-9]+)|([0-9=+-])|( )", line.rstrip("\n")) if x])
```

Comment: "Off topic" or not this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks mate!